# Калькулятор для программиста

Tags: железо, калькулятор

На днях сломался мой ASSISTANT AC-3106.
Посоветуйте калькулятор для программиста чтобы мог переводить в разные системы счисления і т д Я студент-программист и хороший калькулятор в обучении не помешает

Comment: Отдельный гаджет это конечно замечательно, но позвольте поинтересоваться, чем не устраивает тот что в смартфонах или вы на нокии сидите, так бы могли написать калькулятор полностью соответствующий вашим предпочтениям.

Comment: А нокия не телефон чтоли ?)
+ можно и для нокии написать!

Comment: Любой REPL, ghci или python особенно хороши. Python есть для почти чего угодно, от смартфонов (включая Nokia/Symbian), PDA, до телефонов с J2ME и всяких микроконтроллеров.

Или Вам обязательно специализированное устройство?

Comment: Я лишь подчеркнул что нокия не смартфон(хотя есть такие(имелась ввиду 1100 и подобные)). Нокия, в некотором смысле гораздо больше телефон, чем айфон или гэлэкси к примеру, но вбивать на телефонной клавиатуре что-то не 2+2*2 удовольствие сомнительное. Но развожу демагогию - вот хорошая весчь, сам не игрался но от Citizen остались лишь положительные впечатления, несколько штук дома работают до сих пор с 94 на родной батарейке). http://www.unimarket.org/catalog/kalkuljatory/citizen/inzhenernye/citizen-sr-282/

Comment: Кстати нагуглил о проверке, полезная ссылка) http://arbinada.com/pmk/node/97

Comment: А чем уже стандартный калькулятор MS Windows не подходит для расчетов в других системах счисления? 

Если не надо считать тригонометрию - сойдет любая дешевка типа того же ASSISTANT или CITIZEN. Ну а если действительно хочется хорошую вещь - рекомендую "HP 50G".

Comment: @Равнодушный, спорить не буду, т.к. аппарат весьма достойный, но их сейчас вообще производят? В смысле - можно ли купить новый? Или только уже б/у?

Comment: Можно, он же всего 6 лет на рынке. Года два назад брал примерно за $350. Сегодня можно купит на hp.com за $130.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не связан ни с программированием ни с системным администрированием

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Купите что-нить вроде [Canon FX-82MS](https://www.google.ru/search?q=casio+fx-82ms). Это т.н. scientific-engineering calculator. В числе ф-ций - работа с различными система счисления. Еще должно понравиться то, что калькулятор имеет историю команд. Также калькуляторы из этой серии бывают программируемые...